# What is dispatchToken mean in flux Store (Dispatcher.register)?

Tags: reactjs, flux

I practice react recently

I see a code in company projects:

```
const TestStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
   emitReceiverList() {
      this.emit(Constants.RECEIVER_CHANGE) ;
   },

}) ;
//What is .dispatchToken
TestStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(function eventHandlers(event) {
   const action = event.action ;

   switch(action.actionType) {
      case Constants.DEV_SEARCH:
         info = action.value ;
         TestStore.emitReceiverList() ;
         break ;

      default:
         break ;
    }
}) ;

export default TestStore ;
```

And I refactor to :

```
const TestStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

   // emitReceiverList() {
   //    this.emit(Constants.RECEIVER_CHANGE) ;
   // },

   handleActions(action) {
      const new_action = action.action;
      switch(new_action.actionType) {
        case Constants.DEV_SEARCH:
           info = new_action.value ;
           //emit directly
           this.emit(Constants.RECEIVER_CHANGE) ;
           break ;

         default:
            break ;
       }
  }
}) ;

AppDispatcher.register(TestStore.handleActions.bind(TestStore));

export default TestStore ;
```

It stiil works well,but I'm not sure whether there is side effect
So I want to ask what is TestStore.dispatchToken mean for??
Is it needed ???

I google and find this `https://github.com/sasha-bichkov/Flux-app/blob/d3c318f7cc6f33c2a96d76774b85a13acb792879/assets/javascripts/stores/BookStore.js`

```
let BookStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {});

BookStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    default: break;
  }
});

export default BookStore;
```

But I still don not know what is it used for??
Please guide me Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If TestStore requires that another store (BookStore for example) complete updating its data then you can use this token with waitFor() to guarantee that the store has updated its data.

```
 AppDispatcher.waitFor([BookStore.dispatchToken]);
```